# Filter Array of Objects with a Object reside in Nested Array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following use-case,

I have,

- An array of objects that contains a list of `courses`
- An array of objects that contains `students` with a nested `array: studies`

I need to find a courses which are not studied by any student.

How to achieve that?

follow is the code sinnpient.

```
let courses = [
    { id: 'A' },
    { id: 'B' },
    { id: 'C' },
    { id: 'D' }, <-- not studied by any one
    { id: 'E' },
    { id: 'F' }, <-- not studied by any one
];

let students = [
    {
        name: 'STD1',
        study: [
            { id: 'A' },
            { id: 'C' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'STD2',
        study: [
            { id: 'B' },
            { id: 'E' }
        ]
    }

];
```

expected output

```
  const notUsedCourse = [{ id: 'D' }, { id: 'F' }];
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please first try something (use `.filter()`, `.some()`, things like that). Then, if you are really stuck, we can help you. But Stackoverflow is not a free code writing platform. We can help you but not develop the whole solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can save course `id`s which have been studied by `students` into a `Set` so that we can check if a course has been studied later.
The advantage over the solution with `filter` and `some` combination is that this solution will be much faster when the size of `courses` and `students` gets bigger since the former has the time complexity of `O(n^3)` .

```js
const courses = [
    { id: 'A' },
    { id: 'B' },
    { id: 'C' },
    { id: 'D' },
    { id: 'E' },
    { id: 'F' },
];

const students = [
    {
        name: 'STD1',
        study: [
            { id: 'A' },
            { id: 'C' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'STD2',
        study: [
            { id: 'B' },
            { id: 'E' }
        ]
    }

];

const usedCourseIds = new Set(students.flatMap(student => student.study).map(course => course.id));
const notUsedCourses = courses.filter(course => !usedCourseIds.has(course.id));

console.log(notUsedCourses);
```

Comment: Note, that `.flatMap()` instead of `.flat().map()` will perform even better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Though `.flatMap()` is equivalent to `.map().flat()` instead of `.flat().map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to loop through and search if a student has the course:

```js
let courses = [
    { id: 'A' },
    { id: 'B' },
    { id: 'C' },
    { id: 'D' },
    { id: 'E' },
    { id: 'F' },
];

let students = [
    {
        name: 'STD1',
        study: [
            { id: 'A' },
            { id: 'C' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'STD2',
        study: [
            { id: 'B' },
            { id: 'E' }
        ]
    }

];

let notUsedCourse = courses.filter(
  course => !students.some(
    student => student.study.some(
      study => study.id === course.id
    )
  )
);

console.log(notUsedCourse);
```

Comment: It's an easy enough problem for an experienced programmer, and didn't seem like a "write this code for me" question. This one can be a bit tricky with the nested `.some()`s, which is why I chose to answer it. @JeremyThille

Comment: He posted an expected output, a clear problem statement. By all means: This fits our site.

Comment: You were silently downvoted, and my comment, in which I meant no harm and I was only wondering something, was silently censored... classic Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the visited courses first and then filter all courses.

```js
var courses = [{ id: 'A' }, { id: 'B' }, { id: 'C' }, { id: 'D' }, { id: 'E' }, { id: 'F' }],
    students = [{ name: 'STD1', study: [{ id: 'A' }, { id: 'C' }] }, { name: 'STD2', study: [{ id: 'B' }, { id: 'E' }] }],
    seen = students.reduce(
        (seen, { study }) => study.reduce((s, { id }) => s.add(id), seen),
        new Set
    ),
    missing = courses.filter(({ id }) => !seen.has(id));

console.log(missing)
```